# SQL Server : trigger to retrieve duplicates and stop them from being entered whilst inserting new values

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to look for duplicates in a table column. The column `name` is alphanumeric and table is a user-defined table

This is my trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DUPLICATES]
ON [dbo].[AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
   DECLARE @Alphanumericcol VARCHAR (750)

   -- This trigger has been created to check that duplicate rows are not inserted into table.
   -- Check if row exists
   SELECT @Alphanumericcol
   FROM Inserted i, AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl t
   WHERE t.AlphaNumericCol = i.AlphaNumericCol
     AND t.Client_Id = i.Client_Id

   --  (@Alphanumericcol = 1)
   -- Display Error and then Rollback transaction
   BEGIN
       RAISERROR ('This row already exists in the table', 16, 1)
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END
```

The result I get is, if I input a duplicate number it fills in a null in the column so my question is how do I get it to tell me its duplicate and let me insert a new one

Comment: Why not just declare a unique constraint on the column

Comment: are you saying, dont use a trigger just a unique constraint?

Comment: It's what I'd do, unless there's something extra that you've not mentioned in your question. You should always prefer the built in DRI mechanisms (unique constraints, check constraints, foreign keys) over writing triggers.

Comment: OK, i have put a unique constraint on the column, and yes it doesnt allow me to enter duplicate however can i get it to prompt that the number is duplicated or not? sorry but im quite new at this

Comment: If you try to insert with a duplicate key you should get an error: Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Bob' with unique index 'IX_Bob'. The duplicate key value is (1). Check for this exception/error in your code.

Comment: how can i incorporate this into my trigger:

Assuming that is an Alphanumeric field you should be checking what value is in the alphanumeric column from inserted, comparing it with whatever is in the AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl to see if there’s a duplicate

Comment: You don't need or want a trigger just use the unique constraint that is what it is for.

Comment: can you give me an example please